# Would it be a bad idea to extend Context? Android

Tags: android

Context: "This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system"

I was thinking of deriving it to include some handy methods, but I'm not sure what to make of the above line. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that things like `Activity` are indirect subclasses--they won't see your additional functionality.

If your use is isolated and that's okay, then it doesn't matter--just something to be aware of, which *sounds* like it'd reduce the effectiveness of extending at that level, considering how much stuff extends it.